# How to use NSApplication and NSWindow in java to access a window opened in mac and its contents?

Tags: java, eclipse, cocoa

I am a java programmer and the situation demands that I use Objective C or Applescripts in my java code.
How do I use Objective C or Applescripts in java? Any libraries/jars?
I tried "rococoa" library, but it doesn't seem to have NSApplication and NSWindow in it.
Am using Eclipse IDE.

Basically, I want to access a window opened in mac and its contents.

Please share the library/jar, if you have. And a snippet of how to use them.

Comment: Can you also do the opposite: call Java from Objective-C?

Comment: Nope. I have to use Objective C or AppleScript in java. Any idea how?  Would you have a snippet to access a window and its components like ok button or a progress bar in mac? I want to simulate the same using java.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `osascript` command to execute any AppleScript, for example:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Firefox" to quit'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But, how do i access a window and its components/elements in mac using java? Any approach you know of?

Comment: Can you clarify access a window and its elements? What do you exactly need?

Comment: There's a installation window opening up when i try to install a software, I want to access all the elements in that window. It has a label, a progress bar, 'ok' and 'cancel' button. I want to trace the installation progress.